# database design for pickup and deliver addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

I am designing a database for vehicle rental company. Rental company should be able to deliver and pickup the vehicle to customers desired addresses ( both - delivery and pickup can be different). Each of these address will be stored into customer_addresses table below and will be listed for future bookings for customer.

I have created following tables

- booking
- customer
- customer_addresses (FK: customer_id)

Now i want to capture pickup and delivery addresses for bookings. shall i create two tables "pickup_addresses" and "delivery_addresses" each having two column "booking_id" and "customer_address_id"

OR

shall i create a single table "requested_addresses" with two column "booking_id" and "customer_address_id" along with a column "type", where type can take two strings "pickup" and "deliver"

OR

Is it possible to have two foreign keys "delivery_address_id" "pickup_address_id" in the booking table where both referencing to customer_addresses table ?

Each booking will have zero-or-one pickup and zero-or-one delivery address. What would be the best way over here ?

Comment: may be my question is not clear. Well, 1 booking has 2 customer addresses. one for delivery of vehicle to customer at the start of rental and another one for picking up the vehicle from customer at the end of rental. Its like - i need two customer_address_id in my booking table.

Comment: I am using ruby on rails. Does it allow two foreign keys from booking table referencing the customer_addresses table ?

Comment: Yes got it, it allows two foreign keys. But I am not sure if it is correct way to do it. Not all the bookings will be having home deliveries and pickups and thus many of the rows in booking table will have nil values for these columns. However, I guess, going this way will speed up the things. But i am still confused.

Answer (score 1):

You need only one addresses table with polymorphic association.

Tables:

- bookings
- customers
- addresses
- pickups

RailsCasts#[154 Polymorphic Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable
end

class Pickup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable
  # OR for one address
  # has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end
```

Attributes by addresses table for polymorphic association:

- addressable_type
- addressable_id

Comment: But customer can edit/delete their addresses while pickup and delivery addresses will persist always ( deletion won't be allowed on them) do not you think, we should keep customer addresses separate from delivery/pickup addresses ?  

Another issue with this polymorphic approach is - tomorrow my customer address may have different fields than pickup/delivery address. For example, pickup/delivery address may contain lat/lon in future while customer's address may not. 

My idea is to copy customer address into pickup/delivery address at the time of booking checkout.